# Clipboard to Kindle?

Tags: kindle

Recenly I stumbled upon an article on a website and figured I'd rather copy-paste it to my Kindle instead of tiring my eyes. The problem is, I know no fast way to fix it, especially with HTML markup inclusive. Are there any tools for that?

Answer (score 2):

Pasting to a kindle is something I do regularly. But not via creating a pdf, as the pdf reader in the kindle only works well with particular kinds of pdf page formats (single column works well, dual column per page is barely readable, for example).

Really, the web-page needs to be formatted from html to kindle-markup by a specific application.

And fortunately, there is such an application. Instapaper. Even more fortunately, it's free.

The setup is a bit fiddly, But once you have it working, and you find a text-heavy web-site you want on your kindle to study further, it works like a dream.

Here is a walk-through of the instapaper/kindle setup

http://david-smith.org/blog/2012/01/13/instapaper-on-the-kindle/

Comment: The Mobipocket format uses [XHTML markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_e-book_formats#Mobipocket). Mobi, epub, azw, etc. are basically just zipped html files.

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote [a desktop program](http://cdn.yiest.com/download/sctk.zip) to send the text in clipboard to your Kindle device, just by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

This is not a virus. I have put the source code on [Github](https://github.com/yiest/Send-Clipborad-To-Kindle).
I also developed a Chrome extension: [Send to kindle by one click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/%E4%B8%80%E9%94%AE%E5%8F%91%E9%80%81%E5%88%B0kindle/hpphpohoimhpjigccjejlokfkdiaopof).

Comment: Mac compability?

Comment: People should use extreme caution before running applications like the one posted here. I haven't checked the application myself but we have several red flags here. Yiest is a user with 1 rep, the site this is on is a untrustworthy source and the file linked is (basically) an executable. The main application does pass a comprehensive virus scan though: https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/8bcefddb3b9531ca346a0ea55a3a2cda7b446167553bd6e9ea2508e74d1ac658/analysis/1427252047/

Comment: It looks you you created a duplicate user name, which prevents you from editing your own post.  See this on getting the accounts merged: http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts.

Answer (score 0):

There are several free browser extensions that will send a website to your Kindle.

I use [Push to Kindle](http://fivefilters.org/kindle-it/) where you only have to enter your own email address and that of the kindle. You will receive the article's content without HTML, navigation text, or ads.

Answer (score -1):

If your browser is Chrome, you can print the current page to a PDF file. There's an addon that does the same thing for Firefox, and probably other browsers. Once you have a PDF file, you can use [Send to Kindle](http://www.amazon.com/gp/sendtokindle) and use the Kindle's built-in PDF reader.

Comment: PDF's not the best option. The output usually looks terrible.